# Symfony2 array of forms?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.5

Is it possible to create and render and array of forms I know about collections but they don't really fit in my idea?

What I want is something like this

## Controller

```
$data=$em->findAll();
$Forms=$this->createForm(new SomeType,$data);

return $this->render(someView,array("Forms"=>$Forms->createView()));
```

## Twig

```
  {% for Form in Forms %}
  {{ form(Form)}}
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just create your forms in array:

```
$data = $em->findAll();
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    $forms[] = $this->container
        ->get('form.factory')
        ->createNamedBuilder('form_'.$i, new SomeType, $data)
        ->getForm()
        ->createView();
}

return $this->render(someView, array("forms" => $forms));
```

### UPDATED

As mentioned by edlouth you can create each form named separately. I updated my code.

Comment: Thx bro, but I got another problem now when I submit one form it send an array of forms the reason is probably cause all submit buttons have same value.How can I solve that ?

Comment: You need to generate different forms. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to create list of delete forms for every entity so when I click on delete button I want to call some action pass my form ,get data out of it and remove it using doctrine entity manager.

Answer (score 0):

Create the forms in an array, but give each one a unique name.
I've changed it to formbuilder which might not be ideal for you but hopefully something similar will work.  I'm also not certain about putting in `new SomeType` rather than 'form', see http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.html#method_createNamedBuilder.

```
$data = $em->findAll();
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {

    $forms[] = $this->container
        ->get('form.factory')
        ->createNamedBuilder('form_'.$i, new SomeType, $data)
        ->getForm()
        ->createView();
}

return $this->render(someView, array("forms" => $forms));
```

Comment: You could just edit my answer. It has minor modifications from mine.

Comment: I agree I could have done.  I was not aware I could edit, given my reputation, as I attempted to comment but wasn't permitted to, hence assumed I had to give a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony3:

```
$datas = $em->findAll();

foreach ($datas as $key=>$data)
{
   $form_name = "form_".$key;
   $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed( 
      $form_name, 
      SomeType::class, 
      $data
   );
   $views[] = $form->createView();
}
return $this->render(someView, ["forms" => $views]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The action :

```
$forms = [];

foreach ($articles as $article) {
    $forms[$article->getId()] = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed(
        'article_'.$article->getId(), // unique form name
        ArticleType::class,
        $article
    );
    $forms[$article->getId()]->handleRequest($request);

    if ($forms[$article->getId()]->isValid()) {
        // do what you want with $forms[$article->getId()]->getData()
        // ...
    }
}
```

And a better way to render :

```
return $this->render('some_view.html.twig', [
    'forms' => array_map(function ($form) {
        return $form->createView();
    }, $forms),
]);
```